# Making a text based game in c#, how do i create new items to dictionary without name conflicts

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dictionary

I am making a game in C# and I want to be able to create items on the fly and save them to a dictionary.

My question is how do I create a new object form a base class and save it without having like 3 swords in the dictionary all with the name sword?

Essentially the code will look something like:

```
Sword sword = new Sword();
```

How do I then save the above new item to a dictionary with a unique object name?(or at least different) Or can I use an ID based system and just keep track of how many swords I have created and set the ID to something like `"sword" + swordcounter`

Comment: Search for your sword in the dictionairy, if you have a hit you can count the amount of swords and add the counter to the name. after that you can add them to the dictionairy

Comment: Do you have any code you can share? something you already tried

Comment: no sorry, im prototyping new systems for my game and im working out details before i start

Comment: in that dictionary make key as class name that will be unique and the value part contain the list of object that you have created already. It will help you to register the each object of type.

Comment: i may have found a solution, put the creation into a method and instead of the name call an input that makes a calculation of the name base don item being made then i can solve the problem completely form the start.

ie. private void makesword(string swordName)
{
BaseSword swordName = new BaseSword();
}

where swordName is:

string swordName = "SWD" + swordCount;

then just copy that over to whatever im storing items in (if i can get unique names form the start i can reconsider the dicitonary)

Comment: course one issue that occurs is how do i then save it? if the new object name is the same name as an input is vs smart enough to know to add the new sword object to a sword class list?

Comment: nope doesnt let me do that

Answer (score 2):

Your thought about using a static int to uniquely identify swords could work. A better way might be using [GUIDs](https://www.dotnetperls.com/guid) as an identifier property for all the classes in your game, as GUIDs are effectively guaranteed to be unique. The advantage there is you can use the GUIDs as keys in a dictionary (key type:GUID value type: Object), and store different types of objects in that dictionary (rather than just Swords).

Comment: so if i made a new object from a sword class it would have like bxt01 and if i made another it would be bxt02?

Comment: Your Sword class would have a readonly field or property of type Guid, and let's assume you named that field or property "Id". In the object constructor, you would throw in the line Id = Guid.NewGuid(). Then, everytime you created a new instance of your sword class, its Id field would have a unique value, that would look something like this if you printed it to the console: "a2934fa2-6f7e-4ac9-8210-681814ac86c4"

Comment: Note, I just edited my answer since the Dictionary type I suggested didn't appear in it

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of possible approaches, i suggest you to do an Item class as a base for every item and then create a Sword : Item class and store inside a list or an array or a dictionary, every item you make with an ID.

You can still use the array position to track your items but i prefer the ID approach ^^

Comment: how would i go about doing the id without having to manually type in like a thousand ids? id like it to do it automatically

Comment: By tracking your existing items, you will be able to assign an id to every new item by simply "calculating" it automatically

Comment: so if i used "Dictionary.add(key, value" with key being a string concatenating a name and a counter i would be able to have a diff id each time? (if i dont use guid's).

i can probably referance how my old system has the dicitonary.add set up and use that as a base and just change the logic

Comment: I think that you should use numbers and count every item without thinking about the type

Answer (score 0):

Two angles to my answer:

Angle #1 - Why Dictionary?  What does using a Dictionary give you that something like List doesn't?  I mean, unless you plan on having millions of different items and *really* need that performance boost on being able to binary find on a specific ID-Value, I'd think List (or Array) would suit you just fine.

Angle #2 - GUID.  If you're generating a meaningless ID value for each item, you could just use a GUID:

```
System.Guid.NewGuid();
```

That would give you a unique value for any given item which you could use as the Key for your dictionary item.

Comment: i love the GUID thing! i will have a play around with that when i get home from work

Comment: The list should be a better solution in my opinion. A dictionairy with a guid as key is not that efficient is it?

Comment: Oh I agree - I'd use List.  But the place where a Dictionary shines is if you've got a Key you need to look up from a large collection - because it will Binary Find it - aka, O(n) = log(n).  Doing a search on a list will take O(n) = n.  I doubt he'll be populating his Dictionary/List with enough entries that it'll be relevant, but I could be wrong.